# Warning 1292 on update table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update a table with the following query:

```
UPDATE test.t1
SET obrigatorios = (SELECT quantidade FROM test.tcur WHERE tipo = 3)
WHERE perfil IN (7, 11);
```

or this query, should do the same thing:

```
UPDATE test.t1 a, test.tcur b
SET a.obrigatorios = b.quantidade
WHERE a.perfil IN (7, 11)
AND b.tipo = 3;
```

the table tcur has this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `tcur` (\
`quantidade` int(11) default NULL,\
`tipo` int(11) default NULL,\
`descritivo` varchar(12) default NULL\
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

table t1 is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (\
`qtd` bigint(20) NOT NULL default '0',\
`qtd_vt_disp` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',\
`perfil` binary(11) default NULL,\
`obrigatorios` int(11) NOT NULL default '0'\
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I am getting tens of thousands of errors/warnings 1292 about truncated doubles. Where is the problem?
"Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happens when the engine has to convert data types and some precision loss happens because they are not of the same size.

in this particular case, the data type of field `perfil` is binary, should be int.

If you run into the same kind of warning "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value", look for the data types for something not matching.

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth, I found the data type was not the issue when I had a similar problem, it was actually the construction of the MySQL UPDATE statement. Try making the changes manually via MySQL workbench, if you can update manually then examine how the workbench constructs the necessary statement.